# understanding cellFactories and CallBack

Tags: listview, callback, javafx

I am trying to implement a custom cellFactory for a ListView.
My application is based on this sample I took from another thread.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class SO extends Application {
    static class XCell extends ListCell<String> {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        Label label = new Label("(empty)");
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Button button = new Button("(>)");
        String lastItem;

        public XCell() {
            super();
            hbox.getChildren().addAll(label, pane, button);
            HBox.setHgrow(pane, Priority.ALWAYS);
            button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println(lastItem + " : " + event);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(null);  // No text in label of super class
            if (empty) {
                lastItem = null;
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                lastItem = item;
                label.setText(item!=null ? item : "<null>");
                setGraphic(hbox);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4");
        ListView<String> lv = new ListView<>(list);
        lv.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
                return new XCell();
            }
        });
        pane.getChildren().add(lv);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

So for each line of this list will be created a new XCell object from which the hBox will appear.
However I don't undertand how the following things occur despite the documentation:

- this is obscur but I can guess the hBox appears because of ListCell.setgraphics (inherited from the class Labelled).
- in XCell.updateItem(String item, boolean empty), how are the parameters passed to that method?
  A call is made for each string contained in the ListView, which returns a new XCell() but no parmeters is passed to that constructor.

Can someone explain that to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this is obscur but I can guess the hBox appears because of
>   ListCell.setgraphics (inherited from the class Labelled).

Yes, that's correct. From the [documentation for `Cell`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html):

> Because by far the most common use case for cells is to show text to a
>   user, this use case is specially optimized for within Cell. This is
>   done by Cell extending from Labeled. This means that subclasses of
>   Cell need only set the text property, rather than create a separate
>   Label and set that within the Cell. However, for situations where
>   something more than just plain text is called for, it is possible to
>   place any Node in the Cell graphic property. Despite the term, a
>   graphic can be any Node, and will be fully interactive. For example, a
>   ListCell might be configured with a Button as its graphic. The Button
>   text could then be bound to the cells item property. In this way,
>   whenever the item in the Cell changes, the Button text is
>   automatically updated.

Your next question:

> in XCell.updateItem(String item, boolean empty), how are the
>   parameters passed to that method? A call is made for each string
>   contained in the ListView, which returns a new XCell() but no
>   parmeters is passed to that constructor.

You are setting a *factory* on the `ListView`. The factory is essentially a function that creates `ListCell`s for a `ListView`. So the `call(...)` method simply has to return a `ListCell`: in this case you return an instance of your `XCell` subclass.

The way the `ListView` works is (conceptually, at least) as follows:

Initially, it uses the cell factory to create `ListCell`s for each of the visible cells, and lays those cells out. It then figures out which value is to be displayed in each of the cells, and calls the `updateItem(...)` method on each cell, passing in the item. If there is more space than is required for the number of items in the list, it will fill them with additional cells, and call `updateItem(null, true)` to indicate those cells are empty.

As the items to be displayed change: either by the contents of the list changing, or by the user scrolling around (or by other mechanisms, such as the `ListView` changing size, etc), the `ListView` will recompute the items to be displayed and will call `updateItem(...)` passing in new items. This way the cells can be reused as the user scrolls around and the need to create new cell instances is minimized.

Consequently, when you implement `Cell`s, it is important to respect that fact that the `updateItem(...)` method may be called many times, while the creation of new `Cell` instances is relatively rare. So the `updateItem(...)` method should execute quickly; anything more heavyweight should be done once in the constructor. Notice how in the `XCell` implementation you show, the creation of all the `Node`s (`HBox`, `Label`, `Pane`, and `Button`), and the layout, is done on construction. The `updateItem(...)` does this minimal amount of work by just updating the text of the label.

Comment: Would that be possible to "control" which element of ListCell creates a new XCell() ? Like using a for loop, or foreach element in ListCell?

Comment: I don't understand that comment. In any case, it sounds like a different question, so you should probably clarify it and post it as a new question.

Comment: What I mean is XCell extends a ListCell, so is the extended  ListCell a List, as to speak? In the CallBack method, is the ListView associated to one single instance of XCell(), or is it that each element of this ListView is associated to one instance of XCell ?

Comment: None of those. `ListCell` is not a list. The `ListView` creates multiple instances of the `XCell`, but not necessarily one for every element of the list. (At a minimum it creates one for each **visible** element of the list, but has the option to reuse existing instances when some elements become invisible and others become visible, for example when the user scrolls.)